# Are Drupal's hooks an implementation of Interfaces?

Tags: php, design-patterns, drupal

It seems to me that when creating a module you are using Drupal's hooks like an interface, typically the interface that you implement forces the same method names but could it be said that the naming conventions that Drupal institutes conform to this design pattern?

Comment: Don't know about its naming convention, but it's often said that a hooks system is a basic variation of the observer pattern.

Comment: Eh its early today, an interface isn't really a design pattern :) Thanks for the insight Mario, I'll take a peek at observer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://drupal.org/node/547518) is a good article about OOP and Drupal.

> Drupal's hook system is the basis for its interface abstraction. Hooks define the operations that can be performed on or by a module. If a module implements a hook, it enters into a contract to perform a particular task or return a particular type of information when the hook is invoked. The calling code need not know anything about the module or the way the hook is implemented in order to get useful work done by invoking the hook.

However if you have an interface in OOP you need to implement all non abstract methods. With Drupal you just implement the methods you need.

Personally I have found it easier to take Drupal as it is rather than trying to apply OOP concepts to its' architecture.